# How to delete the images in gcr on specfiic time?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-container-registry

I need to delete the images in google container registry which are older than 7 days. Do we have any lifecycle similar to objects in GCS bucket.

Any reference will help a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think there is a direct way to do that, but you could use a script like [this one](https://gist.github.com/ahmetb/7ce6d741bd5baa194a3fac6b1fec8bb7)